# Thermal Conductivity

Tags: heat-transfer, cooling

So a product of me being a bored mechanical engineering student and my love of camping has prompted me to attempt to make my own Seebeck generator. It will be powered by a simple wood fire in a can and slightly fan forced so i am expecting 400+ degrees (celsius).

My question is what would be best to conduct the heat from the fire (ideally from stock i already have), a solid copper round bar (8mm), a thicker aluminium or copper heatsink or copper tubing (6.5mm OD 3.7mm ID). the copper tubing will either be left with void in the center or i had the idea of filling it with lead/tin solder as the fire temperature will most likely be above their melting point and hopefully transfer the heat well.

This is more a thought experiment into whether the solder option will work or it i have missed something crucial like it expanding and exploding on me. i have also heard that fin style heat sinks, like that found on PC's, are terrible conductors of heat as the cross section of their fins are too small to carry large amounts of energy.

Any input is great and i'll probably end up testing them all anyway because there is no better way to learn than by doing.

I drew up some quick plans of what I am imagining[image: Seebeck generator]

Comment: solar cookers use lead/tin to store the heat absorbed... may work well but not if you need to to "flow" between the source and a reservoir - what about a fluid...

Comment: I don't think fins are designed to carry large amounts of energy.  They are designed to have an extremely large surface area compared to the tubing, so I'm sure there's some compensation for lack of temperature just through that effect.  Also basically every large hydronic HVAC system uses coil-fin heating/cooling.  It's definitely effective at what it does; but it might be better suited to the near-ambient temperature ranges instead of 400°C.

Comment: It'd  be easier to comment if you posted some design diagrams.

Comment: It's a good thing this is a "because I can" project, as there are certainly easier ways to generate electricity from a fire :-)

Comment: @SolarMike Do you have any liquids in mind? my initial thought was solder so i could melt it in there, let it solidify and then TIG the copper tubing to a plate. Plus i didn't want anything that would turn to vapour or cause high pressure like water to steam (i know it's only small quantities but once again this is more of a thought experiment)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft To be honest this whole project is just for its wow factor and to give me something to do over the upcoming holidays, i already had a peltier/seebeck module that i bought out of curiosity. I had looked at a small steam turbine design :D but i just wanted something simple that i could just leave go while i sleep and slowly charge a phone or portable speaker

Comment: Ok, -- finstock absorbs just as well as it radiates, so I would go with radiator finstock (fins surrounding Cu pipe), maybe backfill the pipe with solder or any thermally conductive fluid which can handle your anticipated max temp.  That will maximize the heat transfer from fire/exhaust into the metal, and since the only "cool" area is over at the thermoelectric element, the heat will flow that way.

Comment: fluid check out : http://www.globaltherm.org/heat-transfer-fluid/high-temperature-thermal-fluid#.WbvuM62B1E4

Comment: Liquid metal (solder) isn't going to conduct heat better than solid copper, *unless* it is flowing, ie. moving heat by convection rather than conduction. I dont see what in your loop design would drive it to circulate.